# How to use 2 column and their data to compute standard deviation using select query

Tags: mysql, sql, standard-deviation

I have two columns:

[image]

I would like to compute the standard deviation of the column value.

every value to compute STDDEV must be used from student_value.

As shown in the image above, student_id value has multiple value of "28"

I want to sum up column "Value" per "Student_id" and use the data to compute the STDDEV.

```
student_id, value
       -28,     7
       -29,     4
       -30,     6
       -31,     7
       -32,     6
       -33,     9
```

Standard deviation = 1.6431676725155

My current SQL Query is:

```
(SELECT STDDEV(st.total) from 
(SELECT sum(value) as total FROM `main_answer` 
        where ans=correct_ans and center_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
        and exam_id='".$get_exam_status_id['exam_id']."') as st)
```

Comment: Your data, description, and query are not in agreement at all.  Please edit your question and show us a meaningful sample of data along with your current query for that data.

Comment: What do you mean? I have shown the sample table from my database and current query

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sum up column "Value" per "Student_id", you should use:
GROUP BY student_id